# Excel verificação de valor repetido

Tags: microsoft-excel

Como checar no Excel se o valor de uma célula está repetido, valor das linha na mesma coluna,não fiz nenhuma tentativa de comando.Gostaria de saber se existe uma formula especifica?

Comment: Por favor, leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/75104), [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) e [Seja mais específico na pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104). Portanto, evite usar o CapsLock e coloque [valores de exemplo de uma tabela, sendo mais específico](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/).

Comment: Sim, o excel tem um botão de remover duplicatas na barra de ferramentas de dados.

Comment: Ok. Não queria remover e sim sinalizar que está repetido. Tem como? Formatação condicional?

Comment: A última vez que precisei de algo assim, acabei duplicando colunas e criando umas fórmulas. Que eu saiba, não há padrão e formatação condicional não resolve. Vamos aguardar pra ver se alguém aparece com uma resposta detalhada (mas já aviso que Excel não está entre os assuntos mais tratados aqui, pode demorar um pouco).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar formatos condicionais:

[image]